# How to check if text is selected and cross button is pressed in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have a textview. There is label above textview which indicates that textview text is mandatory or not. So if textview is empty label will be visible and as soon as user write any character label is hidden. Now I want to detect if user has selected some text and pressed cross button of keyboard. I used below code it works thought but it is conflicting with other scenario.

So if there any alternate for below code?

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    print(text.length + (textView.text?.length)!)

    if textView.tag == 22 || textView.tag == 23 || textView.tag == 24 || textView.tag == 25 {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: textView.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! WhyTableViewCell

        if text == "" && range.length > 1 {
            cell.lblValidation.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

textDidChange....

Isn’t the test simply

Label.isHidden = !text.isEmpty()

The label is based solely on the amount of text in the text field ? If the text field is empty you want to display the mandatory label. It doesn’t matter if the field was empty to start, a single backspace of one character, the ‘x’ click or a selection and delete, you only display the label when the value of the text field is empty.